# How to load any type of video url on my web application

Tags: javascript, .net, html, iframe, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a feature in Dot Net MVC 5 which says to load any type of video URL in iframe or any other tag. I can have video URL of any type/source. For example:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYbXaqQ3uuo
2. https://vimeo.com/81408697
3. http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xaso79
4. Or any physically located video on my server like https://www.myserver.com/video/testvideo.mp4

I just want to load this URl in my web application without any modification in this URL. Please suggest

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can embed url in html 5 like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="220" height="245" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYbXaqQ3uuo?autoplay=1"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not that easy, i had tried this its giving error of same origin "Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYbXaqQ3uuo' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'." And also it is not applicable for all the video URL